# Using 'git mv' to rename file logs as entire file contents being changed

Tags: git, git-log, git-mv

I have a weird case where I try to track some changes made to a large code file retroactively, the person who made said file saved different versions of the file called `mainV1.py`, `mainV2.py` and `mainV3.py`.

I've placed the first file `mainV1.py` in the repository and commited it (let's call it **commit 1**), then made a name change using the git command `git mv mainV1.py mainV2.py` and commited that (**commit 2**) and then replaced the renamed `mainV2.py` with the actual `mainV2.py` file and commited that (**commit 3**).

I've done the same for `mainV3.py`, creating **commit 4** (renaming) and **commit 5** (replacing the renamed file with the new file).

All this was done to be able to track the changes between `V1`, `V2` and `V3` easily within the repository.

The problem i encounter is that when I look at the diff between **commit 1** and **commit 2** and **commit 3** and **commit 4**, the change is marked to be the entire contents of the file (even though it's marked as a rename in git).
This means that even though the diff between **commit 2** and **commit 3** clearly shows only the relevant line changes, when I diff between **commit 1** and **commit 3** I only see  changes made to the entire contents of the file.

This also has the effect that when I use `git log --follow -- mainV3.py` I only get the 3 commits **commit 1**, **commit 3**, **commit 5** listed.

This is the current state of things. which means that I *sort of* have the changes made to the file tracked in the repository, but i can't for example see the full changes between `mainV3.py` and `mainV1.py` since that is a diff between **commit 1** and **commit 5** and that shows up a full file rewrite.

Anyone knows where I went wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just create a main file, paste V1, commit, replace with V2 content, commit, replace with V3 content, commit? The intermediate ones and the renames are not useful.

Comment: "when I look at the diff" -> what diff viewer do you use ? many graphical diff viewers will show what you describe even when git detects a rename

Comment: 2nd important notion: on a `git diff`, git computes likely renames, but it hasn't stored any information stating "between these two commits, file `mainV1` has been renamed to `mainV2`". If there are lots of changes in commit 3, the renaming detection may not kick in when comparing to commit1.

Comment: so I would go with @Mat's suggestion. If you have some ulterior motive to keep different names, please explain us why.

Comment: @LeGEC - The reason I want to keep the files with different names, is that the different names actually come from different commits.
I'm actually working with a couple of different repos i'm trying to stitch together to keep the history intact (suffice to say my predecessor did not use version control properly).
Since the file names are different between the two repos (and hence the file change histories) I am required to keep the names and create these rename events in the new repo's history to maintain history continuity, even though the file names are originally different.

Comment: @LeGEC, with regards to how I check my diff - I mainly refer to the view I get in using `git log --follow` and when checking diff between file versions using *SourceTree*'s GUI, not sure exactly which diff method they are using.